# How do you put tracking code in a PDFLaTeX file

Tags: pdf, analytics

Suppose I have a PDF page (generated by say PDFLaTeX) that is accessed like a web page would. Is it possible to put a tracking code on it (for usage analytics) in a way similar to an HTML page?

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to LaTeX and friends...

Comment: @CountZero Is there a way of including the tracking codes, that say Google issues, in a LaTeX file so that the resulting PDF file is counted by Google during access?

Comment: If you know what code you want to add to the PDF, there are a couple of ways to embed those in the PDF itself. I think "pdf literals" is the place to start.

Comment: @Maesumi: So you would like to include Google Analytics tracking code into the `(La)TeX` source, so that the resulting `PDF` can be tracked, just like a (`HTML`) web page?

Comment: @CountZero Yes. According to LostBrit this is more of a PDF question not a TeX one. As you said. But at least I know where to look.

Comment: @Maesumi: Great! Then this was helpful after all. `:)`

Comment: @Maesumi well, it's also a latex question in that generating the PDF literals is not always easy.

Comment: @SylvainDurand: And then you need a viewer that always executes that JavaScript...

Comment: To me, it seems that a tracker in a PDF would have to be inserted into the PDF at point of download (as otherwise each file will have the same number). As such, you'd expect to post-process the file: that is done for example by some academic journals. However, you wouldn't use LaTeX for this, so I'm minded to migrate to SO.

Comment: This isn't something that would work unobtrusively -- PDF viewers prompt the user before engaging any Internet-connected functionality. If that's a requirement, the easy answer is "you can't".

Comment: Googeling your question, I got to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30706/example-of-javascript-form-within-pdflatex . But the descripted package insDLJS: http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/acrotex/examples/execjstst.pdf describes how to integrate JS Code to the pdf in latex. So perhaps it will work, creating an AJAX request out of the pdf. I will keep track on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon
It can work where javascript doesn't such as emails, stackoverflow answers or github.